# No Answer should recieve my bounty

Tags: support, bounty

I have posted a question/issue and I recently got a email that my bounty will be rewarded to a answer even if I say so or not.

The answer to my question was not even a right answer nor did the person who posted the answer even comment or try to really answer the question. If he read the previous comments he would have known that I have already did what he put down as a answer.

So could someone tell me will the guy who wrote the answer still be rewarded if he has -1 vote?

Link to thread: [Featured Images are not able to be set](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269061/featured-images-are-not-able-to-be-set)

Comment: Seriously, you are upset because someone that put up some time to answer your question might get some insignificant reward, just because the answer was not good? Side note: the question was bad (not enough details) and off-topic (all errors are off topic), only by miracle you would have got a good answer to it.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Off Topic. Really How?

Comment: hmmmm it is not as explicit as I would assume it should be (not that anyone read the FAQ, but it should be listed there :( ). But in any case errors require access to your code, and if you don't post it how will anyone be able to even make an educated guess?

Comment: @MarkKaplun I did post code. I only post the code that maybe significant. But then yet again if I spammed my post with miles and miles a code people (not trying to be mean) like yourself would tell me that I did that.

Comment: so you think that that code is related, maybe, probably not. Again the issue with errors and "thing do not work for me" is that we do not have access to your setup, so it is up to you to do debugging of the issue to find out the exact cause as no one else can do that. Without that preliminary work you are much less likely to get any good answer.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I'm well aware I did give the errors that were showing up when I would try to set the image. And I was good about providing information. But you didn't answer my question will he still get the bounty?

Comment: @MarkKaplun plus if you looked the guy stole a answer from the comments probably thinking it was the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is, that you did hide the *really valuable and important information* in the comments. You thought, that the warning and the error is unrelated and does not belong in the question — and you are wrong here. If you get information: Put it in the question, if you receive additional information: File an edit. Try to make your question repeatable in anyones setup by removing everything and move back to a default, vanilla installation. Then add only the code that makes your case fail and post this to your question. Developers will likely take your code, pull up a new local installation on their machines and start debugging. If they can not debug, but only guess, then there is no definitive answer. Either your question finally boils down to a typo, a missing semicolon and turned off debug mode. If this is the case, then it's a *syntax error* and off topic.